# jetpack compose java.lang.IllegalStateException: Start/end imbalance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

this piece of code cause this crash:

im using compose version 1.0.0-alpha06

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Start/end imbalance   at androidx.compose.runtime.Composer.finalizeCompose(Composer.kt:2369)   at androidx.compose.runtime.Composer.endRoot(Composer.kt:575)   at androidx.compose.runtime.Composer.composeInitial(Composer.kt:2054)   at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:276)   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:110)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:234)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.kt:-1)   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.kt:627)   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)   at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)

can someone help me? thanks

```
@Composable
@Preview
private fun Image1() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight()) {
        Image(
                asset = imageResource(id = R.mipmap.fit_static_image_1),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
        )
        Column(Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp).align(Alignment.CenterStart), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start) {
            Text(
                    color = getColor(id = R.color.white),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = TextUnit.Sp(18),
                    text = dicString(id = R.string.fit_static_image_1_title),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            )
            Text(
                    text = dicString(id = R.string.fit_static_image_1_description),
                    color = getColor(id = R.color.white),
                    fontSize = TextUnit.Sp(14),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was using **remember { }** wrong, i was trying to use it in **dicString** function to remember obtained string. That caused the issue. I fixed that by adding the resource id to the remember function as parameter. **remember( id ) { }**

Answer (score 26):

I had this happen when returning from a composable due to lack of data from within the construction of a composable.

```
val dataOrNull by viewModel.data.collectAsState(null)

Box {
    MyComposable(
        data = dataOrNull ?: return
    )
}
```

I fixed this by returning prior to constructing the tree

```
val dataOrNull by viewModel.data.collectAsState(null)

val data = dataOrNull ?: return

Box {
    MyComposable(
        data = data
    )
}
```

Comment: This seems like a serious compose bug. Have you seen this anywhere in google bug tracker?

Comment: I haven't checked.  It doesn't seem like a bug, you've started to construct a composable tree then abandoned it mid-function, but the error could be more descriptive.

Comment: It's a normal construct of the language, and I'm sure you can detect it in compiler plugin. Since Google claims that compose plugin should be transparent to the user (just use it and don't care about internals) then in my opinion it's a bug, or more like unhandled edge case

Comment: Another way to do this that still allows the check within the scope is to use a null-propagated let: `Box { dataOrNull?.let { MyComposable(it) } }`. This still works because a Compose element is either returned or not. I agree with @Jakoss that this feels like a leak of the compose abstraction and thus is a bug, it is definitely a tricky edge case to handle!

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same issue on compose version `compose_version = '1.1.0'`
The fix was to remove the `return` statement from a composable function.
Example:

```
@Composable
fun Foo() {
    if (true) return // convert to if-else statement instead of return
    Text(text = "foo")
}
```

Comment: this drove me nuts

Answer (score 1):

I my case with **Koin Dependency Injection** replacing this:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel()
```

by this:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel = getViewModel()
```

resolved my error.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

My use case -

Was calling return from a if check inside BoxScope

```
Box() {
if (state.value == false) return

//doSomething()
}
```

replacing return with return@Box solved this error

```
Box() {
if (state.value == false) return@Box

//doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is facing this in the future, another issue is having `continue` inside loop in Composable such as :

```kotlin
for (direction in MainRoute.values()) {
    if (direction == MainRoute.MAIN_MENU) continue
    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(direction.route) }) {
        Text(text = direction.title)
    }
}
```