# Android Compose - Return inside Composable: Exception: Start/end imbalance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use `return` in Composable method and app is crash.
My issue different [that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893871/jetpack-compose-java-lang-illegalstateexception-start-end-imbalance)

This is my code and Logcat
[image: image-1]

If I put if statement inside HorizontalPager, it will work.
[image: image-2]

Comment: It isn't duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893871/jetpack-compose-java-lang-illegalstateexception-start-end-imbalance